# NoMethodError in admin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm starting to work on the admin backend, and im trying to show ALL applications for the admin to view. I have an application model that accepts nested attributes, but it seems my admin controller cant access them. Here is the code, im surprisingly stuck. The error im receiving is:

```
undefined method 'postsecondaries' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_App:0x00000102452128>
```

Admin Controller

```
class Admin::AppsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @apps = App.all
    @users = User.all
  end


end
```

Index View:

```
<h4>Post Secondary Schools of Interest</h4>
<% @apps.postsecondaries.each do |f| %>
Post Secondary Name: <%= f.postsecondary %><br />
Address: <%= f.postsecondary_address %><br />
City: <%= f.postsecondary_city %><br />
Province: <%= f.postsecondary_province %><br />
Postal Code: <%= f.postsecondary_postalcode %><br />
Country: <%= f.postsecondary_country %><br />
Program: <%= f.postsecondary_program %><br />
Faculty: <%= f.postsecondary_faculty %><br />
Status: <%= f.postsecondary_status %><br />
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :apps
  end
```

Also the public application model:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :postsecondaries, :dependent => :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postsecondaries, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "postsecondaries", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "app_id"
    t.string   "postsecondary"
    t.string   "postsecondary_address"
    t.string   "postsecondary_city"
    t.string   "postsecondary_province"
    t.string   "postsecondary_postalcode"
    t.string   "postsecondary_country"
    t.string   "postsecondary_program"
    t.string   "postsecondary_faculty"
    t.string   "postsecondary_status"
  end
```

Comment: Please post the `Postsecondary` model.

Comment: @zeantsoi the postsecondary model just states belongs_to :app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to access individual attributes on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Instead, you should iterate through the relational objects and access object's attributes individually.

Try traversing one level deeper in your association:

```
<% @apps.each do |app| %>
  <% app.postsecondaries.each do |ps| %>
    Post Secondary Name: <%= ps.postsecondary %><br />    
    <!-- continue iterating through each attribute on `ps` -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@apps` is a `Relation` of `App`s, not an `App`. as such it doesn't have the association method `postsecondaries`.

Presumably, you want to iterate through `@apps` and for each `App` therein, iterate through `postsecondaries`. While you can do that as shown in the answer from @zeantsoi, Rails has a shorthand based on partials that will allow you to avoid the explicit top level iteration by including the following in your `index` view:

```
<% render @apps %>
```

Your `app` partial would then just include the code to iterate through and display the `Postsecondary` elements (or use the same technique with a `postsecondary` partial).  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials for details.

Note finally that since you don't appear to be presenting any information about the rest of the `app` record and are just providing information on the `postsecondaries`, you might want to collect all the `Postsecondary` values first and eliminate duplicates and/or sort them before displaying them.

Comment: So how would you tackle this problem?

Comment: So now I did f.postsecondaries.postsecondary to just get the name. And now it's saying the postsecondary is an undefined method.

Comment: `postsecondaries` is an array of `Postsecondary`, so it wouldn't have a `postsecondary` method.

Comment: postsecondary is a table in the schema. It's were the school name is stored by the user.

Comment: Actually, if it follows normal Rails conventions, the table name is `postsecondaries` (plural), but in any event, Rails protects you from using the database table names directly. As I said, `postsecondaries` will give you an array of `Postsecondary`, so it doesn't have a `postsecondary` attribute. You need to iterate through `postsecondaries`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will have to loop through each app, and then loop through postsecondary to display the information... so try something like this

```
<h4>Post Secondary Schools of Interest</h4>
<% @apps.each do |app| %>
   <% app.postsecondaries.each do |ps| %>
      Post Secondary Name: <%= ps.postsecondary %><br />
      Address: <%= ps.postsecondary_address %><br />
      City: <%= ps.postsecondary_city %><br />
      Province: <%= ps.postsecondary_province %><br />
      Postal Code: <%= ps.postsecondary_postalcode %><br />
      Country: <%= ps.postsecondary_country %><br />
      Program: <%= ps.postsecondary_program %><br />
      Faculty: <%= ps.postsecondary_faculty %><br />
      Status: <%= ps.postsecondary_status %><br />
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will loop through all the apps, and then in turn loop through all the postsecondaries in each app.